# conflicting changes between users

Tags: excel, vba

I created an excel macro for doing some calculations and at the end, save it as SHARED workbook. My problem is I can't find the EXCEL VBA code for activating the option THE CHANGES BEING SAVED WIN within Advanced tab in share workbook option 
[image]
Any idea?

Comment: [Microsoft docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/office/vba/api/excel.workbook.conflictresolution) - [is your friend](https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/office/vba/api/excel.xlsaveconflictresolution)

Comment: I already used this solution but it's not working. I saved my document with this code:

ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:= _
        "E:\Users\Document.xlsm", _
        FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbookMacroEnabled, CreateBackup:=False, accessMode:=xlShared, ConflictResolution:=xlLocalSessionChanges
    bold**ActiveWorkbook.ConflictResolution = xlLocalSessionChanges

and the option what I am asking is still unselected.

Comment: In this case, I suggest you add the already tried code into your question so people who may help will have a basis to start with.

Answer (score 1):

While this doesn't matchup exactly with your screenshot, I think the below approach is how you would deal with this. You want to leverage the property [XlSaveConflictResolution](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.workbook.conflictresolution) property. There's [three ennumerated](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.xlsaveconflictresolution) options (even though your option box shows two). I think this would match what you're looking for:

- **xlUserResolution** = Ask me when changes win
- **xlLocalSessionChanges** = The changes being saved win

Here's an example:

```
ActiveWorkbook.ConflictResolution = xlUserResolution
```

Let me know if this works as I didn't have time to test.

Comment: I used your code: 

ActiveWorkbook.ConflictResolution = xlLocalSessionChanges
  
ActiveWorkbook.Save

because I want to have the option "The changes being saved win" but, when I go to the option in excel manually, I see "Ask me when changes win" option selected :(

Comment: @MoisesCC that may not mean that it didn't work. Have you tested when there's a conflict? It's conceivable that the default setting may not update with VBA.